# How to edit CSS of header logo in WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, css

I have a wordpress theme. I am customizing a website. I have to add logo in header. I have bigger size PNG logo. How to change size of logo using CSS.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We don't do your work for you. Please read the [help] before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the WordPress core custom header feature via functions.php;

Set `'flex-width'    => true` and `'flex-height'    => true`

see this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers